# Julia @spawn and pmap() on an embarrassingly parallel problem that requires JuMP and Ipopt

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing

I'd really appreciate some help on parallelizing the following pseudo code in Julia (and I do apologize in advance for the long post):

```
P, Q   # both K by N matrix, K = num features and N = num samples
X, Y   # K*4 by N and K*2 by N matrices
tempX, tempY  # column vectors of size K*4 and K*2
ndata  # a dict from parsing a .m file to be used by a solver with JuMP and Ipopt

# serial version
for i = 1:N
    ndata[P] = P[:, i]  # technically requires a for loop from 1 to K since the dict has to be indexed element-wise
    ndata[Q] = Q[:, i]

    ndata_A = run_solver_A(ndata)  # with a third-party package and JuMP, Ipopt
    ndata_B = run_solver_B(ndata)

    kX = 1, kY = 1
    for j = 1:K
        tempX[kX:kX+3] = [ndata_A[j][a], ndata_A[j][b], P[j, i], Q[j, i]]
        tempY[kY:kY+1] = [ndata_B[j][a], ndata_B[j][b]]
        kX += 4
        kY += 2
    end
    X[:, i] = deepcopy(tempX)
    Y[:, i] = deepcopy(tempY)
end
```

So obviously, this `for` loop can be executed independently as long as no columns of `P` and `Q` is accessed twice and the same column `i` of `P` and `Q` are accessed at a time. The only thing I need to be careful about is that column `i` of `X` and `Y` are correct pairs of `tempX` and `tempY`, and I don't care as much about whether the i = 1, ..., N order is maintained (hopefully that makes sense!).

I read both the official documentation and some online tutorials, and wrote the following with `@spawn` and `fetch` that works for the insertion part by replacing the `ndata[j][a]` etc. with placeholder numbers 1.0 and 180:

```
using Distributed

addprocs(2)
num_proc = nprocs()

@everywhere function insertPQ(P, Q)
    println(myid())
    data = zeros(4*length(P))
    k = 1
    for i = 1:length(P)
        data[k:k+3] = [1.0, 180., P[i], Q[i]]
        k += 4
    end
    return data
end

P = [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99]
Q = [-0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01]
for i = 1:5  # should be 4 x 32
    global P = hcat(P, (P .- 0.01))
    global Q = hcat(Q, (Q .- 0.01))
end

datas = zeros(16, 0)  # serial result
datap = zeros(16, 32)  # parallel result

@time for i = 1:32
    s =  fetch(@spawn insertPQ(P[:, i], Q[:, i]))
    global datap = hcat(datap, s)
end

@time for i = 1:32
    k = 1
    for j = 1:4
        datas[k:k+3, i] = [1.0, 180., P[j, i], Q[j, i]]
        k += 4
    end
end

println(datap == datas)
```

The above code is fine but I did notice the output was consistently worker 2->3->4->5->2... and was much slower than the serial case (I'm testing this on my laptop with only 4 cores, but eventually I'll run it on a cluster). It took forever to run when added in the `run_solver_A/B` in the `insertPQ()` that I had to stop it.

As for `pmap()`, I couldn't figure out how to pass an entire vector to the function. I probably misunderstood the documentation but "Transform collection c by applying f to each element using available workers and tasks" sounds like I can only do this element-wise? That can't be it. I went to a Julia intro session last week and asked the lecturer about this. He said I should use `pmap` and I've been trying to make it work since.

So, how can I parallelize the my original pseudo code? Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!